# .each not finding all elements first run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that for testing purposes outputs an alert with every element that is found and it will not output all of them if it is only ran once however if it is ran twice back to back it works fine.

```
$(".sub_menu2").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', ''));
    getSubs($(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', ''));
    if('#next_'+$(this).html()==''){
        $('#exp_'+$(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', '')+', #col_'+$(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', '')).remove();
        $('#cat_'+$(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', '')).css('padding-left','12px');
    }

});
```

This does not return all the elements on the page.

```
$('.sub_menu2').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', ''));

});
$(".sub_menu2").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', ''));
    getSubs($(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', ''));
    if('#next_'+$(this).html()==''){
        $('#exp_'+$(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', '')+', #col_'+$(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', '')).remove();
        $('#cat_'+$(this).attr('id').replace('sub_', '')).css('padding-left','12px');
    }

});
```

This does on the second round. I have tried putting a delay in the frist .each function instead of the alert but when I do that it still does not return all the elements. The elements that it is not returning are nested inside a div on the page if that makes any difference.

Comment: can you add a `alert($(".sub_menu2").length)` before each call to `.each()`

Comment: also prefer `console.log()` to `alert()` for debugging code like `console.log($(".sub_menu2").length)`

Comment: You're making an AJAX request?

Comment: The frist time through it says 0 for length then outputs all the alerts with out skipping any then the second time it says 3 for length and outputs all 3 like it should. It is acting like it is running the code before the document is fully loaded but I have a document ready statement at the top of the code so nothing should run until the page is loaded.

Comment: @duffmatthew: If you remove the `alert()` calls from the first loop, does the second still succeed? You need to post a full working example of the problem. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Actually yes I am using an AJAX request.That was the problem. The request was not finished before I ran the code. Thank you.